# How to properly change value of a field that exist in parent and child object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, solid

So i have a parent class Warrior and a Knight class that extends Warrior. Instructions in tasks says Warrior has 2 fields:

- int health = 50,
- int attack = 5

Knight must have attack amount of 7. How to properly change Knight "attack" field
without breaking SOLID rules etc. My code looks like that rn.

```
public class Warrior {

    private int health;
    private int attack;

    public Warrior() {
        this.health = 50;
        this.attack = 5;
    }

    public void setAttack(int attack) {
        this.attack = attack;
    }

-----------------------------------------------

    public class Knight extends Warrior {

    public Knight() {
        super.setAttack(7);
      }
    }
```

And it works just as i want but i think there is a better solution that i cannot find. Can i just change modificator of attack field on public and then go for super.attack?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a no-args constructor for your `Warrior` class that calls an overloaded constructor with `this(50, 5)`.  You can then use `super(50, 7)` in your Child class of `Knight` to call the same constructor, but with different values.

You could also add an overloaded option for only attack as a parameter like `super(7)` if you *really* do not want to pass the health of a `Knight` when it is getting made:

```
public class Warrior {

    private int health;
    private int attack;

    public Warrior() {
        this(50, 5);
    }
    
    public Warrior(int health, int attack) {
        this.health = health;
        this.attack = attack;
    }

    public void setAttack(int attack) {
        this.attack = attack;
    }
}

//Separate Java File
public class Knight extends Warrior {
    public Knight() {
        super(50, 7);
    }
}
```

I would use something like `setAttack` if you need to change the value *after* the object is created.

Comment: It has to be created with attack amount of 7, and i think i can't set it after creating an object so i'll go with overloaded constructor i think

Answer (score 2):

When you need several of objects having the **same** behavior and set of properties, it's **unnecessary** to create a separate `class` for each of them.

You can create as many instances as required, having **only one** `class`.

If you want these objects to have a fixed set of properties (*or only part of the properties to be fixed, and others provided while instantiating the class*) you can create an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), which constants would represent all the kinds of this object you need like `WARRIOR`, `KNIGHT`, etc.

Each *enum-constants* can maintain a fixed set of properties that correspond to one of the specific flavors of your object.

For example:

```
public enum FighterType {
    WARRIOR(5), KNIGHT(7);
    
    private int attack; // add other properties, like health if needed

    FighterType(int attack) {
        this.attack = attack;
    }

    // getters
}
```

And that how your single base class might look like:

```
public class Fighter {
    private String name;        // provided in the client code while creating a new instance
    private int health = 50;    // if you want this property to be the same for every instance, there's no need to assign it inside the constructor
    private int attack;         // comes with the type
    private FighterType type;   // WARRIOR, KNIGHT, etc.

    public Fighter(FighterType type, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.attack = type.getAttack();
    }

    // getters, etc.
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
Fighter richard = new Fighter(FighterType.KNIGHT, "Richard The Lionhearted");
```